# Mysql working select statement fails as view

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this select statement which works as exprected

```
select wp1.idTour as tour,null as Search,g1.id,g2.id from GeoDB g1,
GeoDB g2,Waypoint wp1 join Waypoint wp2 
where wp1.idTour = wp2.idTour and wp1.GeoDB_id=g1.id and wp2.GeoDB_id=g2.id 
union all 
select null as tour,idSearch as Search,PickupLocation,DeliveryLocation 
from  Search where AutoBid_id>0
```

Now the very same statement with

```
Create view Myview as select...
```

fails with

```
ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'id'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: **`Duplicate column name 'id'`** You have `g1.id,g2.id ` twice. Add aliases or remove one `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

In your query result two column have same name `id` as below:

`g1.id,g2.id`

Try this

```
SELECT wp1.idTour AS tour,NULL AS Search,g1.id PickupLocation,g2.id DeliveryLocation
FROM GeoDB g1,GeoDB g2,Waypoint wp1 JOIN Waypoint wp2 
WHERE wp1.idTour = wp2.idTour AND wp1.GeoDB_id = g1.id AND wp2.GeoDB_id = g2.id 
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS tour,idSearch AS Search, PickupLocation, DeliveryLocation 
FROM  Search 
WHERE AutoBid_id>0
```